# Delete function in MySQL not working on next page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, database

I use the delete function in MySQL. It works fine on the first page when an entry contains more than 10 records but the move to next page function not work. 
I have no idea what's wrong with this.

The function I'm using..

```
     **//Delete Function 
   $('.deleteRecord').click(function(){
    var delRec = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'tab_delete.php',
      data: { delRecord : delRec},
      success:function(data){
          alert(data);
      }
    });
   });**
```

Here is the MySQL query.

```
   <?php

include 'config.php';

            $sql = "DELETE from tab_reg where tab_regID = " . $_POST["delRecord"];
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            /*$sql = "DELETE from tab_reg where tab_regID = " . $_POST["delRecord"];*/
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if($result === TRUE){
                echo "Deleted";
                die;
            }
            else{
                echo "Error";
                die;
            }

?>
```

Comment: put alert inside click handler and check for alert? and what is your jquery version?

Comment: try this one  $(document).on('click','.deleteRecord', function(){

Comment: @Dinesh Thanks sir its working :)

Comment: okay. would you please help me I'm stuck in a query. actually, i want to delete a record but data come from two different table and I used to join for display.
now I want just one button and delete that record from the database.
if you write queries for me it's great for me... 
Actually, I'm new SQL have no idea for complex situation  @Dinesh

Comment: @Awis Butt i dont know sql. better you ask question and tag mysql. there are good people here to help you.

Comment: okay but thanks for this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
$(document).on('click','.deleteRecord', function(){
   // rest of your code.
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is an Ajax based paging, then you need to change the below line

```
$('.deleteRecord').click(function(){
```

To

```
$('.deleteRecord').on('click', function(){
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: what is the difference between those two line? can you please provide some explanation?

Comment: This does not help.

Comment: @Simrat Singh still not work and it's simple javascript function.

Comment: @Dinesh - .click event binds the event on the already loaded html if something is created using ajax then it will not bind the event on the new HTML for that you have to use .on('click', function(){}).

Comment: @Awais Butt - Is that Ajax based paging?

Comment: @SimratSingh no using javascript library creating simple javascript function